# Froxlor default IP address for a new domain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, bind

I have a fresh Froxlor 2.16 installation. My installation runs on a server behind a reverse proxy. This reverse proxy handles Letsencypt certificates for a number of services.

Now I want to route all traffic to froxlor through this proxy.

The bind DNS server that is integrated in froxlor should serve my domnain names.

In Settings -> System I can configure the default IP that is defined in the DNS server for a new domain.

It seems that this IP must be one of the IPs of the network interfaces of the froxlor server.

I would like to use the web-facing IP of my reverse proxy as default IP. Can I do this and how?